# How to add a third child process?

Tags: c, linux, process

There is a code with two process. Also need to add  a third proccess. Processes communicate "Hello, world" to each other. Hello, world -> (Hello, world) -> {(Hello, world)}

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
 
int main() {
  int ps[2];
  int pid[2];
  if(pipe(ps)!=0) {
    printf("pipe error\n");
    return 1;
  }
 
  if((pid[0]=fork())==0) { //first process
    close(ps[0]);
    dup2(ps[1],1);
    close(ps[1]);
    puts("Hello, World");
    exit(0);
  }
if((pid[1]=fork())==0) { //second process
    int i;
    char bf[120]="";
    close(ps[1]);
    dup2(ps[0],0);
    close(ps[0]);
    for(i=0;(bf[i]=getchar())!=EOF;i++);
    bf[i-1]='\0';
    printf("from %d: read %d '%i'\n",getpid(),strlen(bf),bf);
    exit(0);
  }
 
  close(ps[0]);
  close(ps[1]);
  waitpid(pid[0],NULL,0);
  waitpid(pid[1],NULL,0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if((pid[2]=fork())==0) { //third process` ? You also need a new pipe between the second and third process.

Comment: On another note, the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an **`int`** which is rather important for the comparison against the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: `printf("...error\n");` is almost always wrong.  Error messages belong on stderr.  Use `fprintf(stderr, "...");`.

Comment: To add to the comment by @WilliamPursell, writing only "error" is often not very helpful. After a system call like e.g. `pipe` fails it will have set `errno` to a specific error code. This error code can be printed using `perror`. Of you can get a nicer string using `strerror`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes I need to do so. But I don`t know how to do it right

Comment: A common technique is to simply do: `if(pipe(ps)!=0) { perror("pipe"); return 1; }`

Comment: @Loki - You have a program which already forks two child processes, and you're seriously  asking _How to add a third child process?_

Comment: I figured out the topic.  Thanks everyone